# Declare a new Text Object in Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to declare a new Text object in Google script so that I can use the methods shown in the following: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text.

However, when I use the syntax style shown in http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_definition.asp, it doesn't work out for me.

What is the syntax for declaring a new Text object and assigning it a string value?

Thank you,
Nicholas Kincaid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to mix things that can't be mixed.

The text Class you refer to is an element of the document class that belongs to the DocumentApp Service.

All the elements of the DocumentApp Service have only specific methods that are described in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/).

It is true that Google Apps Script is based on JavaScript and that you can create objects, assign and read their properties, build function and about whatever you want but you can't create classes that belong to Google service without using Google services ! (this applies to Spreadsheets, documents, drive files, calendars etc...

Hoping I was clear enough.